# Cypher/Neo4j: Get books co-authored with at least one auth from a different country?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am learning Cypher and have a problem that is likely an easy one for someone with more experience.
I created a small graph of authors and publications. The author is FROM a country, as in:

```
person -[:WROTE]-> book
person-[:FROM]-> country
```

Books have one or more authors. I want to find books that were co-authored by persons from more than one country.  In other words, books that have international cooperation for their authorship.
Your advice would be a great help!

Comment: I admit this problem sounds a bit contrived and may be misconstrued as a "home work assignment." Perhaps that is why there are not takers yet?  I simplified the graph in my example. It is a real problem I am facing as I try to learn Cypher and apply it to my own data. Added the [neo4j] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your labels are :Book, :Person, and :Country, and that :Persons can only be from one country:

```
// first find books written by more than one person
MATCH (b:Book)
WHERE SIZE((:Person)-[:WROTE]->(b)) > 1
WITH b
// now match on authors and their countries
MATCH (p:Person)-[:WROTE]->(b)
MATCH (p)-[:FROM]->(c:Country)
// associate books with the number of distinct author countries
// and filter to those with more than one
WITH b, COUNT(DISTINCT c) as authorCountries
WHERE authorCountries > 1
RETURN b
```

EDIT added more commentary below

This approach, using subqueries connected with WITH, lets you only expand out your graph (say, from persons to their countries) only on interested matches. In this case, it saves us from having to expand out and consider the larger graph of ALL books and their authors and their countries...we instead only do this with books that we know have more than one author.

If you do want to do the entire thing in one go, it would look something like this:

```
MATCH (b:Book)<-[:WROTE]-(:Person)-[:FROM]->(c:Country)
WITH b, COUNT(DISTINCT c) as authorCountries
WHERE authorCountries > 1
RETURN b
```

Comment: nailed it. What I really like about this reply is the first detailed query that helped me understand the steps, then the more streamlined one that I can implement after I have the understanding of the mechanics. Applied and verified!